# Split array into four boxes such that sum of XOR's of the boxes is maximum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

> Given an array of integers which are needed to be split into four
>   boxes such that sum of XOR's of the boxes is maximum.
>
> I/P -- [1,2,1,2,1,2]
>
> O/P -- 9
>
> Explanation: Box1--[1,2]
>                Box2--[1,2]
>                Box3--[1,2]
>                Box4--[]
>
> I've tried using recursion but failed for larger test cases as the
>   Time Complexity is exponential. I'm expecting a solution using dynamic
>   programming.
>
> ```
> def max_Xor(b1,b2,b3,b4,A,index,size):
>     if index == size:
>         return b1+b2+b3+b4  
>     m=max(max_Xor(b1^A[index],b2,b3,b4,A,index+1,size),
>         max_Xor(b1,b2^A[index],b3,b4,A,index+1,size),
>         max_Xor(b1,b2,b3^A[index],b4,A,index+1,size),
>         max_Xor(b1,b2,b3,b4^A[index],A,index+1,size))
> return m
> def main():
>     print(max_Xor(0,0,0,0,A,0,len(A)))
> ```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Provide the maximum Array size and the maximum value.

Comment: @Rafi not sure about the constraints.

Comment: You could create an array `B` of the same size and in position `i` store the XOR of the elements from `0` up to `i` of the original array. Note that you can compute the XOR of the elements from `j` to `i` by doing `B[i]^B[j-1]. Then you can loop through the possible cuts at i_1 < i_2 < i_3.

Comment: The code you posted looks like it calculates an arbitrary division of the elements into 4 boxes, and not looking for three cuts to mark 4 consecutive sections. Please clarify which kind of "split" the task requires.

Comment: The array elements in the boxes need not to be consecutive. Hope that clarifies the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to speed up your algorithm:

1. Build in some start-up logic: it doesn't make sense to put anything into box 3 until boxes 1 & 2 are differentiated.  In fact, you should generally have an order of precedence to keep you from repeating configurations in a different order.
2. Memoize your logic; this avoids repeating computations.
3. For large cases, take advantage of what value algebra exists.

This last item may turn out to be the biggest saving.  For instance, if your longest numbers include several 5-bit and 4-bit numbers, it makes no sense to consider shorter numbers until you've placed those decently in the boxes, gaining maximum advantage for the leading bits.  With only four boxes, you *cannot* have a num from 3-bit numbers that dominates a single misplaced 5-bit number.

Your goal is to place an odd number of 5-bit numbers into 3 or all 4 boxes; against this, check only whether this "pessimizes" bit 4 of the remaining numbers.  For instance, given six 5-digit numbers (range 16-31) and a handful of small ones (0-7), your first consideration is to handle only combinations that partition the 5-digit numbers by (3, 1, 1, 1), as this leaves that valuable 5-bit turned on in each set.

With a more even mixture of values in your input, you'll also need to consider how to distribute the 4-bits for a similar "keep it odd" heuristic.  Note that, as you work from largest to smallest, you need worry only about keeping it odd, and watching the following bit.

These techniques should let you prune your recursion enough to finish in time.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Dynamic programming here to break the problem into smaller sets then store their result in a table. Then use already stored result to calculate answer for bigger set.
For example:

```
Input -- [1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

We need to divide the array consecutively into 4 boxed such that sum of XOR of all boxes is maximised.
Lets take your test case, break the problem into smaller sets and start solving for smaller set.

```
box = 1, num =  [1,2,1,2,1,2]
ans = 1 3 2 0 1 3
```

Since we only have one box so all numbers will go into this box. We will store this answer into a table. Lets call the matrix as DP.

```
DP[1] = [1 3 2 0 1 3] 
DP[i][j] stores answer for distributing 0-j numbers to i boxes.
```

now lets take the case where we have two boxes and we will take numbers one by one.

```
num = [1] since we only have one number it will go into the first box.
DP[1][0] = 1
```

Lets add another number.

num = [1 2]

now there can be two ways to put this new number into the box.

```
case 1: 2 will go to the First box. Since we already have answer 
for both numbers in one box. we will just use that.

answer = DP[0][1] + 0 (Second box is empty)

case 2: 2 will go to second box.
answer = DP[0][0] + 2 (only 2 is present in the second box)
```

Maximum of the two cases will be stored in DP[1][1].

```
DP[1][1] = max(3+0, 1+2) = 3.
```

Now for num = [1 2 1].
Again for new number we have three cases.

```
box1 = [1 2 1], box2 = [], DP[0][2] + 0
box1 = [1 2], box2 = [1], DP[0][1] + 1
box1 = [1 ], box2 = [2 1], DP[0][0] + 2^1
```

Maximum of these three will be answer for DP[1][2].

Similarly we can find answer of num = [1 2 1 2 1 2] box = 4

```
1 3 2 0 1 3 
1 3 4 6 5 3 
1 3 4 6 7 9 
1 3 4 6 7 9
```

Also note that `a xor b xor a = b`. you can use this property to get xor of a segment of an array in constant time as suggested in comments.
This way you can break the problem in smaller subset and use smaller set answer to compute for the bigger ones. Hope this helps. After understanding the concept you can go ahead and implement it with better time than exponential.

Comment: Is this answer describing DP for an arbitrary division or for making three cuts to create 4 boxes with consecutive elements in each? OP clarified in the comments that the elements in each box need not be consecutive.

Comment: Yes this DP solution is to make three cuts and put elements consecutively. I just saw the comment which states that they can be distributed arbitrarily in the boxes.

Comment: @MohdWaseem Thaks for the continuous split solution.

Comment: @MohdWaseem Please help with arbitrarily distrubuting solution with idea posted in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would go bit by bit from the highest bit to the lowest bit. For every bit, try all combinations that distribute the still unused numbers that have that bit set so that an odd number of them is in each box, nothing else matters. Pick the best path overall. One issue that complicates this greedy method is that two boxes with a lower bit set can equal one box with the next higher bit set.

Alternatively, memoize the boxes state in your recursion as an ordered tuple.

Comment: The problem with this is that there can be a huge number of options with the highest bits set. (Consider the array [31, 31, 31, 31, . . . 31].) So this is faster than the OP's approach -- polynomial time instead of exponential -- bit nowhere near as fast as a DP approach.

Comment: Imagine partitioning the first *i* elements into *k* subarrays, taking the XOR of each subarray, and taking the sum of those *k* XORs. Let DP[k][i] be the maximum possible sum over all such partitions. You can compute DP[1][i] in O(1) time given DP[1][i-1], and DP[k][i] in O(i) time given DP[1][...] and DP[k-1][...], using the fact that conditionalMethod mentions in a comment above. That gives you the overall result, DP[4][n], in a total of O(4n^2) time.)

Comment: @ruakh isn't what you propose covering splits into contiguous sections in the original order? I am familiar with DP for a contiguous split. OP clarified in the comments that the task is an arbitrary division.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. In that case, I'd be interested to see details about your approach. Can it achieve polynomial time?

Comment: @ruakh my guess is not in the worst case. Do you have an approach that would? I can't get my head around avoiding the need to backtrack if we are unable to set the current bit in all boxes, since we may have a different arrangement where the next higher bit is set in a maximal number of boxes that would allow setting the current one.

Comment: @ruakh clearly if the range is significantly bound, we can have polynomial time via memoizing the recursion the OP proposed.

Comment: Re: "Do you have an approach that would [achieve polynomial time]?": No, I do not. Actually, I kind of wonder if the OP might be mistaken about the problem (s)he's expected to solve. But if his/her understanding is correct, then I think you're right about approaching it bit-by-bit.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Please help by putting some implementation. for suppose if there are 5 numbers with the highest bit set. First 4 numbers can be put in 4 boxes and how to decide in which box 5th number can be put?

Comment: @Deep as Prune suggests, how about looking at which placement of the 5th number-with-highest-bit-set would be most advantageous for placing the remaining numbers with the second (or whichever is next) highest bit set? (My answer suggests to try all combinations but clearly restrictions on the next bit arrangement can help prune the better possibilities.)